# Find the smallest Distance between all possible combinations for a primary key with a condition - SQL

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, Table 1 is where for different tripID's and the stops involved in them. Table 2 is where I have Zip codes and the distance associated.

NOTE: Entity ID and EntityType in the Image and sql Code are the same thing. Was a mistake on my part while uploading the picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGnZb.jpg)

The Yellow highlighted is the result I am expecting to get.

Desired output : For every Individual Trip, I want to take just the Entity 2 type zip codes and compare with every entity 1 and which ever Entity 2 has closest distance to the Entity 1 then have that distance.

For Example in trip 2, I have two different Entity 2 and one Entity 1, now based on table 2 Stop Z is closer to Y as compared to X and hence it is showing distance as 8 which is the distance between 9000 and 8000.

In the example of trip 1, There is only one distinct Entity type 2 and hence distance from A to every stop is captured as a result.

I tried this so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE Final AS 
SELECT table1.*,
       Distance,
       MIN(CASE WHEN EntityType = 2 THEN Distance END) OVER (PARTITION BY TripID ORDER BY StopNumber) AS min_DistanceInMiles
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN 
   Table2 b
ON 
   Table1.Entity_Zip_Code=b.FromZipCode
   AND Table1.From_Zip_Code=b.ToZipCode
ORDER BY 
   TripID,StopNumber asc
```

But I am simply struggling to do this is SQL, any help appreciated here. Thanks!

Comment: There's no `EntityType` column in either table. Is that supposed to be `EntityID`?

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be entity ID, Let me update my questions. Thanks for that!

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support for how to post tables in questions, rather than using a screenshot.

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags. Pla add tbe one back that you actually use

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery that, for every row in `table1`, finds the closest distance by searching for all `entity_id`s that have a value of `2` for the given `trip_id` and then performing a `left join` on `table2`:

```
select t1.*, (select min(coalesce(t3.distance, 0)) from table1 t2 
   left join table2 t3 on least(t2.from_zip_code, t1.from_zip_code) = least(t3.from_zip_code, t3.to_zip_code)
      and greatest(t2.from_zip_code, t1.from_zip_code) = greatest(t3.from_zip_code, t3.to_zip_code)
    where t2.trip_id = t1.trip_id and t2.entity_id = 2) 
from table1 t1
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/blwEadJZ)